# Fast Evaluation and Jacobian of multivariate function

Tags: julia

Related to another [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77783527/julia-block-banded-matrices-construction-from-arrays-improve-speed/77783685#77783685), how can I more efficiently evaluate a function and compute its Jacobian?

Using dual numbers from ForwardDiff.jl and the following functions, I can create a "dual vector" and functionally accomplish this task. This code fits into an iterative numerical solver and from what I have read, computing the Jacobians is the one of the more computationally expensive parts of numerical solvers.

I am curious if the stack overflow community has any suggestions for how to write this in a more computationally efficient manner. In particular, the calculations of `flux_results`, `flux_real`, `flux_dc`, and `flux_d∇c` are the most expensive.

```
using ForwardDiff

function create_interface_dual_vectors(N::Int)
    #Preallocate the dual_vector with the correct type and size
    dual_vector = Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 2*N}}(undef, N)
    ∇_dual_vector = Vector{ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 2*N}}(undef, N)
    
    for i in 1:N
        derivative_part = zeros(N*2)
        derivative_part[i] = 1.0
        dual_vector[i] = ForwardDiff.Dual(0.0, derivative_part...)

        derivative_part = zeros(N*2)
        derivative_part[N+i] = 1.0
        ∇_dual_vector[i] = ForwardDiff.Dual(0.0, derivative_part...)
    end

    return dual_vector, ∇_dual_vector
end


function FLUX(; c_vars, ∇c_vars) # (; c_vars, ΔV)
    c1, c2, c3 = c_vars
    ∇c1, ∇c2, ∇c3 = ∇c_vars

    Diff_coef = 1.0e-4

    # Initialize 'result' based on the type of 'c_vars'
    result = fill(typeof(c_vars[1])(0), length(c_vars))

    result[1] = -Diff_coef * ∇c1
    result[2] = -Diff_coef * ∇c2
    result[3] = -Diff_coef * ∇c3
    
    return result
end
```

```
N = 3
NJ = 102


# interface variables
c_interface = randn(N, NJ-1)
∇c_prev = randn(N, NJ-1)

# create the dual arrays
interface_dual_vector, ∇_dual_vector = create_interface_dual_vectors(N)

# make the interface variables dual valued
c_interface_dual = c_interface .+ interface_dual_vector
∇c_dual = ∇c_prev .+ ∇_dual_vector

# iteratively evaluate the function FLUX
flux_results = [FLUX(c_vars = c_interface_dual[:, i], ∇c_vars = ∇c_dual[:, i]) for i in 1:NJ-1]

# partition the results into the real and dual values
flux_real = [res.value for j in 1:NJ-1 for res in flux_results[j]]
flux_dc   = [flux_results[j][i].partials[k] for j in 1:NJ-1 for i in 1:N, k in 1:N]
flux_d∇c  = [flux_results[j][i].partials[k] for j in 1:NJ-1 for i in 1:N, k in (N+1):(2*N)]

flux_dc  = reshape(flux_dc,  N, N, NJ-1)
flux_d∇c = reshape(flux_d∇c, N, N, NJ-1);
```

Comment: One suggestion is not to use global variables or to make them `const`. For example: `Diff_coef`. Also, there is https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: That's fair. I pushed `Diff_coef` inside of `FLUX`. My main concern is with evaluating FLUX and then partitioning the results into the real and dual-valued portions (`flux_real`, `flux_dc`, `flux_d∇c`. Is the vector compression used here generally advisable? I thought there might be some obvious patterns to exploit, but perhaps that is not the case.